# Options for caching data from the database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

My code already has things like this in the controller:

```
    [OutputCache(Duration = 86400]
    public string SelectTopics(bool showAll = true, string topicID = null) 
    {
        return SelectHelper.Topics(showAll, topicID);
    }
```

Am I correct in saying this will be cached?

How about in external non-controller classes and methods. Is there any way I can have database caching with these or must all database caching be through a controller? What about other ways/means of accessing the data. Anything else that allows caching?

Comment: do you want to cache html output or list of items from database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I correct in saying this will be cached?

This caches the entire HTML output. It means that the controller action will not even be executed if the output is cached. And in this case the `SelectHelper.Topics` won't run.

Other ways of caching data involve using classes in the [System.Runtime.Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.aspx) namespace. They allow you to store NET objects into cache. For example you could store the results retrieved from a database call into the cache and then check whether the cache contains those results before hitting the database the next time. You may take a look at the [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) class for an example.

Comment: Thanks Darin, You mention that the controller action will not be executed. However am I correct in saying I will still get back the same string each time the action is called until the time the cache expires? If that's the case it would be fine because topics don't change frequently.

Comment: @Melissa, you are absolutely correct by saying that each request will get exactly the same HTML output until the cache period expires. Be careful though: if this HTML contains some user specific parts (say for example you have a section where you are saying "Welcome John" where John is the name of the currently logged in user). Since the page will be cached and all subsequent requests will fetch this page from the cache, if Marry logs in to your site and requests the page she will see "Welcome John" since she will be seeing the cached version of the page.

Comment: +1 @Darin, you always be specific with appropriate level of details :-)